# Integer optimization in Mathematica?

Tags: math, wolfram-mathematica, mathematical-optimization

I have an integer programming problem. I have a pipe, 10m long. I want to cut out as many 1.2meter pieces as I can and then cut the rest of the pipe in 100mm pieces. I have to leave 100mm for the machine to grab. How do I optimize this in mathematica? I can solve it as an equality i guess but if i just want the answer straight out.
Basically, as many y's as possible, then x:es.

`Maximize[{x*100+y*1200, x*100+y*1200<9900},{x,y},Integers]` just gives me an inequality plot.
And yes, I have checked instructions at wolfram.

Comment: What works is Maximize[{y, {x*100+y*1200==9900,x>=0,y>=0}}, {x,y}, Integers]

Answer (score 3):

As 9900 and 1200 are both multiples of 100, the algorithm is just

```
TotLen = 9900;
numberOf1200pieces = IntegerPart[TotLen/1200];
numberOf100pieces  = IntegerPart[(TotLen - 1200 numberOf1200pieces)/100];

Print["Number of 1200mm pieces: ", numberOf1200pieces];
Print["Number of 100mm pieces: ", numberOf100pieces];
Print["Leftover: ", 9900 - numberOf1200pieces 1200 - numberOf100pieces 100,"mm"];

Number of 1200mm pieces: 8
Number of 100mm pieces: 3
Leftover: 0mm
```

You may also try:

```
Maximize[{x*100 + y*1200, x*100 + y*1200 == 9900}, {x, y}, Integers]
->{9900, {x -> 3, y -> 8}}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use assume on `x,y` etc to be `>0 etc` and you will finally be able to get a value with `//N`

Mathematica doesnt assume you are in the Real world!

Comment: Maximize[{x*99+y*1200, {x*99+y*1200<4900,x>0,y>0}},y,Integers] does not work either.

Comment: @johnny The second argument must specify all variables.

Answer (score 1):

Belisarius's [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5439343/integer-optimization-in-mathematica/5439765#5439765) is the simplest method via `Maximize`.  However, it requires changing the inequality to an equality, which does not reflect your intent.  Instead, using v. 7, I'd add a second condition

```
Maximize[{x*100 + y*1200, x*100 + y*1200 <= 9900, y > x > 0}, 
         {x, y}, Integers] -> {9900, {y -> 8, x -> 3}}
```

The new condition (`y > x > 0`) reflects your intent that the larger pieces be chosen first better.  Also, note that I changed the inequality (`<`) to `<=` as your divisions come out to 9900 exactly.

Comment: In my machine your eq. gives `{9900, {x -> 3, y -> 8}}`

Comment: I was fiddling with `<` not `<=` which gives `x->2` not what the code gives. :P

Comment: This is good, but depending on the coefficients, it could still give less than perfect results.  Is there a way to specify a dual maximization where y is made as large as possible?

Comment: @Mr. The maximum y is always `IntegerPart[TotLen/1200]`

Comment: @belisarius yes; this is a toy example I think, I am wondering about more general use of `Maximize`, as I suppose is johnny

Comment: @mr. Ohhh Probably you are are referring to the `Optimal cutting problem`. That's a hard one :D

Answer (score 1):

To answer the simple question at face value, rather than inferring it to be a toy example of optimization, here is one method of "unitizing" a number.

```
Floor[ FoldList[Mod, #, Most@#2] / #2 ] &[ 9900, {1200, 100} ]
```

---

Responding to belisarius' implication that my reply was *too* naive, I think this may be a valid, albeit inefficient method for more complicated cases.  Consider splitting 9950 into lengths 12, 75, and 1200.

```
i = 9950;

While[x = Quiet@IntegerPartitions[i--, All, {12, 75, 1200}, 1]; x === {}]

x[[1]] // Tally
```

Comment: The usual problem is a little more subtle because you don't want leftovers. Suppose you have [16, {5, 3}] as input. You may give {3,0} or {2,2} as a result. The last one without leftovers. The general case is a very well studied problem, and there are a lot of commercial products for it. Almost every factory has this kind of problem in some production stage.

Comment: @belisarius That is a deeper problem that the OP may be wanting to solve, and I would like to see a solution using Mathematica.  Nevertheless, the question says: "I want to cut out as many 1.2meter pieces as I can and then cut the rest of the pipe in 100mm pieces."  I think that my naive code does this.  Am I wrong?

Comment: ahhh you are too susceptible today :)! I was _just_ trying to state that the problem gets really weird when you add a few simple constraints, not to mention in the real world. Perhaps my insistence comes from years ago, when I was involved in solving this same problem for a big Avery's paper coil cutting site. It was quite a project. Please accept my apologies if I've been offensive in any way, as that wasn't my intention.

Comment: @belisarius I certainly did not take offense.  Can you give me a link an example of the more advanced optimization problem you are talking about?

Comment: See for example http://www.math.tu-dresden.de/~belov/publ/downl/1point5-D/sx_nyy.rtf.doc

Answer (score 0):

```
decideOrderOfProduction[itemsToProduce_] := 
 Map[#[[1]] &, Sort[itemsToProduce, #1[[2]] > #2[[2]] &]]
minimizeWaste[pipe1_, pipe2_] := {
  Maximize[{pipe1*x + pipe2*y, pipe1*x + pipe2*y <= 4900, 
    y >= x >= 0}, {x, y}, Integers]
  }
minimizeWaste[pipe_] := {
  Maximize[{pipe*x, pipe*x <= 4900, x >= 0}, x, Integers]
  }
planProduction[itemsToProduce_] := {
  productionOrder = decideOrderOfProduction[itemsToProduce];
  strategy = {};
  While[Length[productionOrder] >= 2,
   pipe1 = productionOrder[[1]];
   pipe2 = productionOrder[[2]];
   strategy = 
    Append[strategy, {pipe1, pipe2, minimizeWaste[pipe1, pipe2]}];
   productionOrder = Drop[productionOrder, 2];];
  If[Length[productionOrder] == 1,
   strategy = 
    Append[strategy, {productionOrder[[1]], Null, 
      minimizeWaste[productionOrder[[1]]]}]];
  strategy
  }


items = {{99, 1}, {200, 12}, {1200, 2}, {90, 5}, {70, 1200}};
decideOrderOfProduction[items]
planProduction[items]
```

```
{70, 200, 90, 1200, 99}

{{{70, 200, {{4900, {x -> 10, y -> 21}}}}, {90, 
   1200, {{4890, {x -> 1, y -> 4}}}}, {99, 
   Null, {{4851, {x -> 49}}}}}}
```

Thats a start but it is bad because somehow I need to take into account priority better and I need to finish the amount of each pipe. Somehow I guess amount needs to be taken into account into priority as well.